# how do i make my function returns multiple values within my for-loop? (Beginner)

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I made a function that uses the `np.roots()` to calculate the roots of a cubic function after I solved for coefficients `p1`,`p2`, and `p3`. I'm trying to make it return multiple roots.

Here is my code:

```
def Q():
     .
     .
     .
    coeff = [1,p1, p2, p3]
    roots = np.roots(coeff)

    #prints out the real positive root

    for i in range(0, len(roots)):
        if np.isreal(roots[i]):
            return np.real(roots[i])
                 
    return 

root = Q(T1,P1,Tc,Pc)
print(root)
```

output:

```
root 1
```

what I want:

```
root 1
root 2
.
.
.
root n
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't exactly return values in a loop: `return` stops the execution of the function and returns control to the caller. You have to compute all the stuff you want to return up-front, and return it all at once.

In this case, you can select elements from your array using a mask. This is especially easy because [`np.isreal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isreal.html) is vectorized: it's meant to operate on your whole array at once, not just individual elements. So you can get rid of the entire loop and write

```
return roots[np.isreal(roots)]
```

The `yield` keyword is an alternative to `return` that does sort of allow you to return multiple values. Using `yield` turns your function into a generator, which you can iterate over until it stops yielding values. To make a generator, just replace `return` with `yield` in your loop.

Both versions of the function will return an iterable rather than a single value. You can then either print in a loop or all at once. The loop looks like this:

```
for root in Q():
    print(root)
```

To print all at once, you can join the strings with newlines:

```
print('\n'.join(str(root) for root in Q()))
```